# How do I create an X509 Certificate in PHP without the clients private key?

Tags: php, cryptography, certificate, openssl

I have a server which has its own cert and a client who is trying to have the server generate a new cert for him (and sign it ofc). The client has given the server his public key and the server is supposed to create a cert and sign it. In PHP, how do I have the server create the cert with only the clients public key? openssl_csr_new seems to want the private key.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably can't to this since CSR needs to be signed with the private key that matches the public key inside the CSR.

Comment: Andris is right, force your client to send a valid (signed) CSR and use the convenient `openssl_*`-functions. Theoretically you could generate a X.509 Certificate with only the public key (and other info like the Subject) but then you have to write your own X.509 formatter and somehow sign the result of that (I have never done THAT I'm pretty sure there is a lot of pain involved).

Comment: i dont understand why this functionality isnt available though, it seems rather useful. can i take an existing certificate and change the signature on that? (i.e. pretend a cert is a csr?)

Comment: The signature of the CSR must be made with the private key that matches the public key in the CSR. So you can't "fake" a CSR without having the correct private key. It might work if the `openssl_csr_sign` wouldn't check the signature but I strongly suspect/hope that it does. And as for altering the Certificate: there is no function for that, you would also have to write your own X.509 implementation (at least the output/writing-part, the keyword is ASN.1).

Comment: No one should ever have the private key but the owner of the key pair. The CA certainly doesn't need it to issue a certificate. Of course you want to make sure that the originator of the CSR really has the private key, and that *can* be done with a signature, but if this for a toy app where you are just trusting the originator anyway, you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with the latest SVN of [phpseclib, a pure PHP X.509 parser](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  eg.

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$privKey->loadKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----');

$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----');
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);
$subject->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'whatever');

$issuer = new File_X509();
// load the DN from an existing X.509 cert
$issuer->loadX509('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----');
$issuer->setPrivateKey($privKey);

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setStartDate('-1 month');
$x509->setEndDate('+1 year');
$x509->setSerialNumber(1);

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
```

You'll need your private key and the subjects public key.  In this example, I'm getting the issuing DN from a X.509 previously signed by with your private key but you might want to call setDN() instead?